# How to run a php code, only if the "submit" button redirect you.

Tags: php

This is my admin panel code:

```
<form action="connectdb.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

So, It so, the code in connectdb.php will only run, if the "submit" button redirects a user to it. It will not run, if a user directly open /connectdb.php page.

Do I need to start some session, something like that?

Note: I am a newbie, so please explain in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your form is using `method="post"`you can place the following code at the very beginning of your connectdb.php file:

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST)){
   exit;
}

//The rest of your code goes here
```

This checks to see if the $_POST variable either does not exist or does exist but is empty. If this returns true that means your form was not submitted and a user went to the page directly. The script will then exit and a blank screen will be displayed.

Instead of displaying a blank screen, you may instead want to redirect to a different page such as this:

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST)){
    header("Location: index.html");
    exit;
}

//The rest of your code goes here
```

Whenever you do a redirect like this, it is important to place an exit; statement directly after it, otherwise your script could still process some of the other statements and send data to the browser that shouldn't be sent. This of course could be a security risk in some cases. An exit statement prevents this kind of security risk.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you really need it, but you can add a `name` attribute like the following:

```
<input name="submit_button" type="submit">
```

So when you click this button a `$_POST['submit_button']` variable will be created on the PHP side, and then you can use it to check if the button was clicked:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_button'])){
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_btn">
```

Now in your connectdb.php check,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
{
    //do your code
}
else
{
 //redirect to your home page
}
?>
```